# PHP: Calculating percentage tax applied to a product

Tags: php, rounding

I've got a significant problem in working out the percentage tax applied to a product, due to the rounding.

For example:

If you have a product which is £1.00 including 20% tax the break down would be:

```
0.83 ex tax
0.17 tax
1.00 total
```

However, if you work out the percentage increase:

```
round( (( ( 1 - 0.83 ) / 0.83 ) * 100), 2);
```

The answer is `20.48`, because the actual price ex VAT is `0.8333333333`

Therefore if you calculate:

```
round( (( ( 1 - 0.8333333333 ) /0.8333333333 ) * 100), 2);
```

You get the correct answer of `20`.

In this case it would obviously work to round the `20.48` down to `20`, but thats not a solution because some tax rates are to 2 decimal places so the assumption can't be made that you can just round the tax rate.

**Am I missing something or is this impossible without knowing the original tax percentage?**

Comment: This can hardly be considered a programming question at all. If you drop precision at some point, you can't just get it back magically. Whatever, doesn't the UK have fixed VAT rates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`0.17` is not `20%` of `0.83`, so your basic assumption is inaccurate( is rounded :P ).

Don't round money, calculate it without all that rounding and display rounded if need be. That avoids having to loose the precision in calculations.

A simple test will demonstrate

```
$price=0.8333333333;
$taxRate=21.25;
$tax=$price*$taxRate/100;
$total=$price+$tax;
$calculatedTaxRate=(($total-$price)/$price)*100;      // 21.25
```

Since we didn't round anywhere, we can reverse engineer the tax rate always down to the dot.

Try with 20%

```
$price=0.8333333333;
$taxRate=20;
$tax=$price*$taxRate/100;
$total=$price+$tax;
$calculatedTaxRate=(($total-$price)/$price)*100;      // 20
```

Comment: It's a difficult problem, because most products are provided with a ex. vat and a inc. vat value, from external sources. I agree this is the best solution though!

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it something like:

17% VAT

85.47 taxless

85.47x0.17 = 14.53

Total: 100

So 100/1.17 = 85.47

Comment: fabulously simple! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My little-and-dirty version:

```
$taxrate=22; // 22%
$price=100;
$priceMinusTax=($price/(($taxrate/100)+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are dealing with low precision numbers, you will get a low precision answer. If you must show low precision numbers, you can round them when you show them to the user in the view, but save them as high precision numbers in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your total price is £1 and tax rate is 20%:

```
$vatDecimal = (float) 1 + (20 / 100);
$priceExclVAT = round((1.00 / $vatDecimal), 2);
$priceDisplay = number_format($priceExclVAT, 2, ',', '.');

echo $priceDisplay;
```

Answer (score 0):

The user enters the total amount and tax. Sometime its come form database, we can also use this code.

```
$actualPrice        =   "";
$total              =   1000;//User Entry Total Amount
$gst                =   18;//User Entry GST Tax %
$calculateTax       =   100+$gst;
$calculateAmount    =   $total*100;
$actualPrice        =   $calculateAmount/$calculateTax;
echo $actualPrice       =   round($actualPrice,2);
echo $gstAmount         =   round($total-$actualPrice,2);
```